# Cytoscape: How can I control the size of the resulting PDF in inch or cm?

Tags: cytoscape

I am exporting a network as PDF ("Export" --> "Network to Image") for publication purposes.

How can I control the size of the resulting PDF in inch or cm?

==

Cytoscape 3.8.0-SNAPSHOT

Java 11.0.4

Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the current implementation always exports 8.5 x 11 inches. It's just some default. We have looked into the Java PDF-exporter library, however, and it looks like we can add support for a few more feature, including dimensions. So, we have opened an feature issue and will work on it.